# Custom template - typeahead-popup-template-url with webpack

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, webpack-2

I am migrating an angular (1.6.2) app from gulp to webpack 2. I am using angular-ui-bootstrap with typeahead-popup-template-url attribute. It looks like

```
typeahead-popup-template-url="app/somePathHere/custom-popup.html"
```

How can I use it with webpack? I am getting an error message :

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: app/somePathHere/custom-popup.html
```

I don't think it is a matter of path. Tried all combinations I could think of. Plus when I migrate angular components I have to replace

```
templateUrl : 'app/somePathHere/some-component.html',
```

with

```
template : require('./some-component.html'),
```

Could it be something similar?

BR

Comment: Solution is present on https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6494